# Вызвать html проверку поля js

Tags: javascript, html, form

Подскажите пожалуйста, можно ли как то вызвать проверку поля на заполненность `required` (пример ниже) с помощью js для отправки ajax запроса без `<form>`.

```html
<form>
<input type="text" required>
<input type="submit" value="go">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Содержимое тега `input` попадает в его атрибут `value`. Просто сделайте проверку `if(!document.getElementByTagName('input').value)`. Если поле не заполнено, то его `value` будет `undefained`, что для `if()` неявно приводится к `true`